# ambiguous call to function template (reverse)

Tags: c++, templates

This code compiles with GCC, but gives `ambiguous call to overloaded function` for MSVC:
https://godbolt.org/z/W89xn15d3

```
#include <string>

template <typename Iter>
void reverse(Iter begin, Iter end){
  if (std::distance(begin, end) == 0)
    return;
  
  auto left = begin,
    right = std::prev(end);

  while (left < right)
    std::swap(*left++, *right--);
}

std::string reverseWordsInString(std::string str) {
  reverse(str.begin(), str.end()); // ambiguous call
//   reverse(str.data(), str.data() + str.size());

  size_t wordLength = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (str[i] != ' ')
    {
      ++wordLength;
      continue;
    }
    
    const size_t offset = i - wordLength;
    reverse(str.data() + offset, str.data() + i);
    wordLength = 0;
  }

  // reverse(std::prev(str.end(), wordLength), str.end()); // ambiguous
  reverse(str.data() + str.size() - wordLength, str.data() + str.size());

  return str;
}
```

MSVC output:

```
example.cpp
<source>(16): error C2668: 'reverse': ambiguous call to overloaded function
<source>(4): note: could be 'void reverse<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>>>(Iter,Iter)'
        with
        [
            _Elem=char,
            Iter=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>
        ]
C:/data/msvc/14.33.31631/include\xutility(5619): note: or       'void std::reverse<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>>>(const _BidIt,const _BidIt)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
        with
        [
            _Elem=char,
            _BidIt=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>
        ]
<source>(16): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>>, std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>>)'
        with
        [
            _Elem=char
        ]
Compiler returned: 2
```

Who is wrong and why?

Comment: [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) finds `std::reverse` and normal lookup finds `reverse` - compiler confused.  Change `reverse(str.begin(), str.end());` to `::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());`

Comment: @RichardCritten ok, makes sence. But `std::reverse` is included in `<algorithm>` which is not included. GCC compiles it, but MSVC does not

Comment: Standard header files __may__ include other Standard header files.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I also look through that forum. If a programmer take part in that forum it does not mean that he is low-qualified. So I am sorry if I offended you. I just compared it with SO.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Also I would like to point that instead of the function std::swap you could use std::iter_swap: std::iter_swap(left++, right--); Good luck!:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll get the same error in GCC if you `#include <algorithm>`. MSVC is including `<algorithm>` implicitly when you `#include <string>`.

The portable solution is to either:

- rename your function to something that doesn't exist in the standard library
- be explicit about the namespace when you want to call your function:

  ```
  ::reverse(...);
  ```
- place your function in a namespace of your own, and then prepend the call with that namespace.

  ```
  myns::reverse(...);
  ```